# How to calculate response time from website using TIdTCPClient or another Indy client component?

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy

I have an application that sends and receives data from a given website with TIdTCPClient - looks like this :

```
TCPClient.Host := myHost;
TCPClient.Port := myPort;
TCPClient.Connect;
TCPClient.IOHandler.Write(clientRequest);
TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadStream(clientResponse, size, False);
```

where `clientRequest` is created dynamically and `clientResponse` is what the server (the wanted website) sends as a response.So my question is how can I calculate the average response time from the website my TCPClient has connected to ?

Comment: What is your problem? Measure the time or calculating average?

Comment: If you are talking to a website, why are you using `TIdTCPClient` and not `TIdHTTP`?

Comment: @Remy Like I said in my question - any Indy client would do the job as long as someone provides a solution for calculating the website response time - I just have two applications - one with TIdHTTP and one with TIdTCPClient and provided example code only from one of them.

Comment: @SirRufo I will have to write code for both but measuring the time is with bigger priority.

Comment: @Roman_Bezjak: nothing in your question mentions "any" Indy client, or the fact that you have another app that uses `TIdHTTP`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at Indy's `Ticks()` and `GetTickDiff()` functions, for example:

```
uses
  ..., IdGlobal;

var
  StartTicks: LongWord;
begin
  ...
  StartTicks := Ticks;
  TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadStream(clientResponse, size, False);
  Elapsed := GetTickDiff(StartTicks, Ticks);
  ...
end;
```